# Can Civ V support internet multiplayer with casual log-out/log-in?

Tags: civilization-5

I've been talking with a couple of long-distance friends of mine about setting up a turn-based strategy game that we can play casually over a period of several weeks, or even months. What we really want is something where people can periodically log in, play their move and then log out again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We might be able to help tell you if Civ V allows that aspect, but we don't do game recommendations.

Comment: You might wanna take a look at [the giant multiplayer robot](http://multiplayerrobot.com/), used it and it work fairly well.

Answer (score 4):

This is what the Pitboss feature is for. Set up a dedicated server with a Pitboss game and players can log in and take their turn at their leisure.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible for Civilization 5 using [Giant Multiplayer Robot](http://multiplayerrobot.com/).

Giant Multiplayer Robot handles games by storing the save file, allowing players to download and play it when it's their turn. It has password protection to prevent people taking other players' turns and is generally more reliable than the mess that is Civ 5's live multiplayer.

Additionally, since everything is handled by storing the save file, you don't need to keep a server running.

The GMR devs also intend to add support for Beyond Earth in the near future.